# Facebook Connect send SMS with PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I created an application in Facebook and now I would like to notify my users whether a certain event has happened by sending them a text message. I have already included the sms permissions to my application, but I can't find any examples/documentation showing me how to properly send it with PHP.

The following is what I have so far:

```
 $smsrequest = $this->facebook_connect->fb->api('/sms.send/', 'GET',
      array(
           'uid'         => $user_id,
           'message'     => $message
      )
 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sms.send was deprecated
http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/deprecations/
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=82649

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I was a bit confused with why Facebook would still have the sms permission on their page if they had deprecated sms.

Comment: I know! Came across this today and I was confused too. Well anyway its too bad that its gone. I had an idea for an app which planned to make use of this but now its not gonna see the daylight. :/